# Integrate with Chartboost objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, chartboost

I've successfully integrated Chartboost rewarded video, it works but i want to implement the code that will increase credits when a user has completely watched a rewarded video. I've tried to implement in app delegate and it works calling it but due to some internal functions i will need to implement in specific view controller. so when i put the same code

```
 -(void)didCompleteRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location
                     withReward:(int)reward {

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really reset?" message:@"hi ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // optional - add more buttons:
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert show];


}
```

the alert view will not appear if i implement this code in specific view controller instead of appdelegate. i assume it is not called in view controller since it has no response. i need help to implement in view controller

Comment: use uialertcontroller instead of uialertview. You need to show code of where u r calling the above method

Answer (score 0):

In order to make UI changes, you should call it on main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really reset?" message:@"hi ?" delegate:self     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
// optional - add more buttons:
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
            [alert show];

        });
```

Or you can just pass the delegate of the view and show the alert on it.

```
-(void) DisplayMessage:(NSString*)message withDelegate:(id)delegate
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                               message:message delegate:delegate
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Comment: but my problem is how to make sure the void is called.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Do you want to make sure this method (didCompleteRewardedVideo) is called and returned?